# Google map is not appearing

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

Google Map is not appearing. I think problem is with data type of lat and long. Here is the code:
All the function works fine when hard coded values of lat long are provided.

```
function initialize(a, b, zoom) {
    alert('init called  ' + "lat: " + typeof a + "long: " + typeof b + "zoom: " + typeof zoom);
    //here lat long are string and zoom is number 

    //var zoom =parseInt(zoom);
    var a = parseFloat(a);
    var b = parseFloat(b);
    alert('init called  ' + "lat: " + typeof a + "long: " + typeof b + "zoom: " + typeof zoom);

    //here lat oang and zoom all are number
    var centerLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(a, b);

    var mapProp = {
        center: centerLoc,
        zoom: zoom,
        //   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: centerLoc,
        title: 'Click to zoom'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

here is the html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:1000px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd be better off asking this on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ , it would also be useful to include a live example, for example post it on http://jsfiddle.net/, saving others setting up a similar environment.

Comment: Where is the associated html, is #googleMap and element and does it have a height and width?

Comment: yes please post the related html, and/or add a jsfiddle.net of your work to see the progress

Comment: @ Revolution42, Yes html has #googlemap with height and width

Comment: @David Chase I have updated the question with html included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.  The only issue is you can't do:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Because you can't pass arguments to a function called that way.  If you use it in the body tag as an onload function, it works:

```
<body onload="initialize(-33.8665433, 151.1956316,5)">
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_initializeMap.html)

Comment: What arguments are you providing?  Your code works fine for me.  Your problem must be something not included in your question.  Please provide enough details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: both latitude and longitude are string and zoom is number when passed to function. function Is called, arguments are passed, their values also displayed in alert but just google map is not appearing.